# Exporting an SQL table to CSV with commas escaped?

Tags: mysql, csv

I have a large MySQL table (8-9k records, I'm using phpMyAdmin) with some values that are descriptions, with commas.

I need to Export the SQL table into CSV form to use on a new platform and I can't for the life of me solve this issue:

When there are commas in certain fields, the data gets shoved to the next column and things get out of order.

I JUST NEED the EXACT table in MySQL to become a CSV. Any tips, ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution was exporting as an .xlsx from MySQL. The columns were rendered perfectly. Using *several* combinations of enclosing/escaping character was to no avail.

I then saved the .xlsx as a .csv and it was fine.

Thanks for your time guys.

Answer (score 6):

Use this query:

```
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE 'filename.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
ESCAPED BY '\\'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM [tablename]
```

**Source**: http://www.wausita.com/2011/02/mysql-export-csv/

Comment: When I replace [tablename] with my table, this query returns an empty set for my table..? Google is not my friend.

Comment: Did you enclose your tablename in ticks?
Like this:
`FROM \`tablename\``

Answer (score 4):

Simply go to the database's *Export* tab. Be sure to **enclose your fields.** This way values are wrapped in `"` to avoid erroneous commas.

Otherwise, you can use `mysqldump` from the command line.

Or you can export data with a query:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/table.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

Comment: If you read my question you'd see I am using phpMyAdmin indeed and I have ALREADY done an export from that tab.

Comment: Yes. You're missing a key step of enclosing the fields.

Comment: I have already used " to enclose the fields; Some descriptions also have " and thus the same error happens. This query returns an empty set for my table..

Comment: We are not going to be able to provide you with exact code. Ultimately your problem lies in *escaping* and *enclosing*. One of these answers should put you on the right path. But you're going to need to do some work yourself.

Comment: How can an outfile be accessed through phpMyAdmin? Though it returned an empty set, maybe the file is still there with populated data.

Comment: It can't, it's stored as specified by `OUTFILE`. Underneath the *Export* tab does the same thing, with the same options. Again, you just need the right combination of *escaping* and *enclosing*.